# How to use a CSS selector on a javascript list?

Tags: javascript, contains

Why does this not work?

```
var animals = ['Cat', 'Dog'].valueOf;

if ("animals:contains(Cat)") {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: javascript doesn't know anything about css. you need to use a javascript function, not a css selector.

Comment: What HTML are you using, and what result do you expect to get? As for your `if`, it looks like you'd want to use `if (animals.indexOf('cat') > -1)`, using [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). The reason it doesn't work, though, is because that's not how you use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`indexOf` method of `Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
if(animals.indexOf('Cat') != -1){
    // ...
}
```

Any string that isn't empty (`""`) will be [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), so the body of the `if` will always run if you do `if("some string")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a CSS selector on an array in Javascript. You can use `indexOf` to see if a particular string exists in the array.

```
if (animals.indexOf('Cat') > -1) {
  console.log('We have kitties.')
}
```

The only time you'd really use a CSS selector in Javascript is when you're querying the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want something like [JSONSelect](http://jsonselect.org/#docs):

> JSONSelect defines a language very similar in syntax and structure to
>   CSS3 Selectors. JSONSelect expressions are patterns which can be
>   matched against JSON documents.

Note that `:contains` is not a standard CSS psedo-class, but JSONSelect provides it as an extension.

```js
var animals = ['Cat', 'Dog'];
if (JSONSelect.match(':contains("Cat")', animals).length) // truthy
  document.write('There is a cat');
if (JSONSelect.match(':contains("Elephant")', animals).length) // falsy
  document.write('There is an elephant');
```

```html
<script src="http://jsonselect.org/js/jsonselect.js"></script>
```

But of course, this is overkill. Better use approaches explained in [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/237104/1529630).

Comment: Something like this. 
In other word, what I need is: If this contains that change CSS of another element